# What can reset cursor shape apart from SetCursor?

Tags: c++, winapi, cursor, reset, apimonitor

I maintain a C++ application that uses flash ocx to play SWF file.

When user hovers on button in SWF, flash internally makes a call to WinAPI `SetCursor` function to set `IDC_HAND` cursor - I can see that when I monitor WinAPI calls to cursor-related function via [API Monitor V2 (rohitab.com)](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor). However, in my case the cursor is not changing, i.e. stays `IDC_ARROW`.

The application itself does not call `SetCursor` at all. The window of the application processes `WM_SETCURSOR` message as following, i.e. does not restore the cursor:

```
case WM_SETCURSOR:
    {   
        static bool restoreCursor = false;
        if (LOWORD(lParam) != HTCLIENT)
        {
            restoreCursor = true;
        }

        if (restoreCursor)
        {
            restoreCursor = false;
            // DefWindowProc will set the cursor
            break;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Can anyone please let me know who can reset/change cursor shape in this case?

**Update**: The interesting part is the fact that I have 2 similar setups that produce the opposite results.

The application I maintain actually installs a `WH_GETMESSAGE` hook on "SysListView32" and launches a thread that creates Flash player. So the setup is not that straight-forward.

However, if I just create a simple example that creates a player at, basically, winmain, then the code above works perfectly and cursor gets changed.

So it appears that something does reset the cursor state in the first case. How to find out **what resets the cursor**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the real answer on this question is that non-GUI thread cannot change the cursor directly.
See the comments in the bottom of the page
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Another solution can be detouring/hooking the SetCursor function to ours that just sends a user message to GUI thread, signalling to set the cursor.

Both solutions have their pros and, of-course :), cons.

Answer (score 1):

Your window (the parent) gets a crack at overriding the cursor and returning TRUE (1) indicated that you handled it and halts further processing. The arrow is probably coming from your WNDCLASS registration or from DefWindowProc.

So, it seems to me that you'd want to return FALSE to allow the child button a crack at actually setting the cursor. Or, remove handing WM_SETCURSOR altogether.

Comment: I believe DefWindowProc sets the cursor based on the WNDCLASS, so it isn't either/or but both working together.

Comment: Wait a sec, doesn't child get WM_SETCURSOR first? So, if child does not process WM_SETCURSOR then it goes to parent via DefWindowProc. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/21/1115695.aspx

Comment: The thing is that the code above **works** if I use a sample application and create a player in pretty much winmain(). But it does not work in my application that does the same but there are hooks and other threads involved. Moreover, both applications (actual and sample) produce **identical** output in WinAPI monitor software.

Comment: Based on your exapanded info, your could try setting a breakpoint in the ::SetCursor() OS api (add a dummy call and step into it in disassembly mode and set a bkpt). You'll need to disable the breakpoint and make it a conditional breakpoint since it'll get hit a lot. But maybe in your mousemove code set a flag which will trigger the bkpt then mouse-over the button.

Comment: I have done that, however the breakpoint is only hit once and that happens from Flash.ocx, which is correct. Nevertheless, the cursor shape is not changing from default arrow. I suspect the cursor is reset by some window's DefWindowProc. And since there is no call to SetCursor detected it means that DefWindowProc resets the cursor via another method.

Comment: How about SetSystemCursor(), try a bkpt in there.

Comment: jschroedl, thank you for your help! Unfortunately, the answer was from another side. It appears that non-GUI threads cannot set the cursor.